# Restriction of function to be continuous from the right

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $f\colon [a,b]\to \Bbb R$ be a function. The goal is to prove there exists a set say $Q$ such that $f\restriction Q$ is continuous at $a$ from the right. Here is the information that we have:

(1) There exists a decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\rightarrow a$   and $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(a)$;

(2) For each $n\in \mathbb N$ there exists  $Q_n\subset(x_n-\frac{1}{n},x_n+\frac{1}{n});$

(3) $|f(x)-f(x_n)|<\frac{1}{n}$ for every $x\in Q_n.$

Now, $Q=\bigcup_{n<\omega} Q_n\cup \{a\}$. We need to prove that $f\restriction Q$ is continuous at $a.$ Here is my attempt :

(*) for all $\epsilon>0$ there $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in Q$ with $a<x<a+\delta.$

since $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ there $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_n)|<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq n_0.$ By using this, together with 2 and 3, we can prove (*) as follows $$|f(x)-f(a)|<|f(x)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$ Does that correct

Comment: try to show that the set of points of right-continuity is residual, e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, how this would help ?

Comment: It shows the existence as $[a,b]$ is Baire.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, In my real example, $Q$ is a perfect set

Comment: Every residual set in $[a,b]$ contains a perfect set.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Maybe it is something basic I misunderstood your reason. Could you state all needed information please ?

Comment: Are (1) - (3) additional assumptions on $f$?

Comment: Paul Frost. Yes, this is correct. What did you think about my explanation ? Is it enough? If not what  I should do.

Comment: Paul Frost, Is it clear now for you ?